# Is there a way to access the comments I make on YouTube through the API?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to retrieve the comments I've made on YouTube to turn them into Markdown files, but I can't find a way to do it filtering by user in the API documentation.

I thought it would be possible since the Google account [has a link for it](https://myactivity.google.com/u/0/page?hl=es&utm_medium=web&utm_source=youtube&pli=1&page=youtube_comments) but when using the parameter "channelID" in the API to list comments as it says in [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/list), it gives back a 400 error.

Comment: I don't think this feature is available on YouTube Data API, however, I do recall reading about a beta test/version of the YouTube app mobile that returns your comments; I don't know the current status of that feature on mobile version. You might give it a try and research about this feature.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the comments your channel posted, however when using [CommentThreads: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/list) with `channelId=YOUR_CHANNEL_ID` you are listing comments people wrote on your channel, [as described the documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/list#channelId):

> **channelId**
>
> **string**
>
> The **channelId** parameter instructs the API to return comment threads containing comments about the specified channel. (The response will not include comments left on videos that the channel uploaded.)

One more time YouTube Data API v3 AFAIK doesn't provide this basic feature.

You have two possibilities:

1. Use [Google TakeOut](https://takeout.google.com/settings/takeout) (make sure to export `Comments` in `YouTube and YouTube Music`)
2. Web-scrap the [webpage](https://myactivity.google.com/u/0/page?page=youtube_comments) you provided

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I didn't understand what "about the specified channel" meant. I guess it means "on your channel" as in the deprecated "comments" tab inside a channel rather than in a video. Doesn't return anything though, and I think my channel had those comments. Guess they're lost now

Comment: And yes, I originally intended for this to be something that works with the Takeout file, but then I found out about the API and thought it would be nice if instead of me having to manually download the takeout, and run the script, automating it. Webscraping it could be an option though, there's probably a way to periodically scrape to at least save me having to generate the takeout, although I don't know if authenticating will be a problem, or if scrapers can get pass the "load more comments" thing in that webpage

Comment: May you share your channel id ? To make sure that retrieving comments posted on your channel are correctly retrievable using [CommentThreads: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/list).
I experienced scraping the YouTube UI, you can get pass the "load more comments" thing in that webpage, my concern is how long the authentication parameters work once manually retrieved.

Comment: To make it clear AFAIK, for a given YouTube channel [`allThreadsRelatedToChannelId`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/list#allThreadsRelatedToChannelId) means comments posted by people on these channel `videos` and `community` tabs and [`channelId`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/list#channelId) means `video` comments posted by people.

Comment: My ID is UCMwkvIenW1NBPlcipr7l1Dg. Maybe I was using the API wrong but when I tried the 2nd option in the docs that I linked with my channel ID (part: snippet, channelID: mine, rest empty) i get back the 400 (The API server failed to successfully process the request) error. And the channelID is correct because if I put it on the 3rd option for example (part: snippet, allThreadsRelatedToChannelId: myID ), I do get back comments other people have left on my channel

Comment: The word `mine` isn't part of the webpage [CommentThreads: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/list), so don't try anything with `mine` using `CommentThreads: list` endpoint. By the way you are right: the `channelId` parameter used to work (I am 100 % about it), but it doesn't anymore...